# Count a specific letter in a string

Tags: c#, string

New to c#. I want my program to count the amount that a specific letter appears in a string.

```
public static int countLetters(string word, string countableLetter)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (char c in word)
    {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: But you don't check your `c` is equal to `countableLetter` in your foreach statement. And `countableLetter` would be better as a `char` type in method parameter..

Comment: `int count = word.Count(ch => ch == letter)` providing that `letter` is `Char`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you searching for exact character then change the second paramater type to `char`:

```
public static int countLetters(string word, char countableLetter)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (char c in word)
    {
        if(countableLetter == c)
           count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

But you can do it with `Count()` method which included in `System.Linq` namespace:

```
return word.Count(x => x == countableLetter);
```

***Additional:***

If you want to find any char which contains in any string, then you can use:

```
public static int countLetters(string word, string countableLetters)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (char c in word)
    {
        if(countableLetters.Contains(c))
           count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

or with LINQ:

```
return word.Count(x => countableLetters.Contains(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Enumerable.Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535181(v=vs.100).aspx) for that:

```
var count = word.Count(ch => ch == countableLetter);
```

Note you should change `countableLetter` to a `char` instead of a `string`.